# List chromes registered service workers

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, service-worker

Is there a way to list all the browsers registered service-workers?
Lets say that I have registered/installed a few service workers.
can I get a list an array of the file names via js?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't an API to list registered workers since Web Workers have limited access to `window` `document` and `parent`. 
A simple workaround would be to store Workers references into a JS object...

Comment: It would help to know exactly what you mean by "all the browser's" and "I" in your question. Do you really want all the service workers registered by any page in any scope? Or do you just want all the service workers registered by pages in a given scope? And is "I" a Firefox/Chrome extension or a web page?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Apparently I have found two ways that works fine for me (for chrome):
one is using shortcut command:

```
chrome://serviceworker-internals/
```

Other one is:

go to `Developers Tool -> Resources -> Service Workers`

Answer (score 27):

There isn't a way to get "all the browser's" registered service workers programmatically from a web page, since a web page can only access the service workers that are registered for its scope.  But if you're looking for a way to get those, then call `navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations` to get a promise that resolves to an array of registered service workers:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function(registrations) {
  registrations.forEach(function(v) { console.log('service worker: ' + v) });
});
```

Answer (score 13):

If you really want to get "all the browser's" registered service workers, you can do it non-programmatically by opening these URLs:

## Firefox

```
about:serviceworkers
```

## Chrome

```
chrome://serviceworker-internals/
```

## Opera

```
browser://serviceworker-internals
```

See also: [Is ServiceWorker Ready?](https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/#debugging) for an up-to-date list of debugging helpers.

---

*(Presumably there's also a way to do this programmatically in a Firefox extension.)*

Comment: "(Presumably there's also a way to do this programmatically in a Firefox extension.)" I suspect this is no longer the case for web extensions :|